# spring-boot RabbitMQ shutdown after consuming aws-java-sdk

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aws-sdk, aws-iot, spring-rabbit

we are using **spring-boot-1.5.6** along with RabbitMQ. The application was working fine till I consume **software.amazon.awssdk:2.7.17**. After consumed awssdk dependency we are getting below issue from RabbitMQ,

```
{  
       "timestamp":"2019-08-16T09:56:22.213+00:00",
       "logMessage":"Consumer thread error, thread abort.",
       "class":"org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer",
       "level":"ERROR",
       "error":"java.lang.BootstrapMethodError: call site initialization exception java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:341) java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSiteImpl(MethodHandleNatives.java:307) java.lang.invoke.MethodHandleNatives.linkCallSite(MethodHandleNatives.java:297) software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.transformHeaders(ApacheHttpClient.java:272) software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.createResponse(ApacheHttpClient.java:257) software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.execute(ApacheHttpClient.java:237) software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient.access$500(ApacheHttpClient.java:102) software.amazon.awssdk.http.apache.ApacheHttpClient$1.call(ApacheHttpClient.java:217) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeHttpRequestStage.executeHttpRequest(MakeHttpRequestStage.java:66) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeHttpRequestStage.execute(MakeHttpRequestStage.java:51) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.MakeHttpRequestStage.execute(MakeHttpRequestStage.java:35) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:64) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallAttemptTimeoutTrackingStage.java:36) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:77) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.execute(TimeoutExceptionHandlingStage.java:39) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.doExecute(RetryableStage.java:113) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage$RetryExecutor.execute(RetryableStage.java:86) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:62) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.RetryableStage.execute(RetryableStage.java:42) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:57) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.StreamManagingStage.execute(StreamManagingStage.java:37) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.executeWithTimer(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:80) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:60) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.execute(ApiCallTimeoutTrackingStage.java:42) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.RequestPipelineBuilder$ComposingRequestPipelineStage.execute(RequestPipelineBuilder.java:206) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:37) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.pipeline.stages.ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.execute(ExecutionFailureExceptionReportingStage.java:26) software.amazon.awssdk.core.internal.http.AmazonSyncHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonSyncHttpClient.java:240) software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.invoke(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:96) software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:120) software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.BaseSyncClientHandler.execute(BaseSyncClientHandler.java:73) software.amazon.awssdk.core.client.handler.SdkSyncClientHandler.execute(SdkSyncClientHandler.java:44) software.amazon.awssdk.awscore.client.handler.AwsSyncClientHandler.execute(AwsSyncClientHandler.java:55) software.amazon.awssdk.services.iot.DefaultIotClient.registerThing(DefaultIotClient.java:7093) com.service.actions.AwsThingsRegisterAction.handle(AwsThingsRegisterAction.java:51) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:333) org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190) org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:741) org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157) org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:85) com.rabbit.RabbitDiagnosticAspect.aroundHandleRequest(RabbitDiagnosticAspect.java:25) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:629) org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:618) org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:70) org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:168) org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92) org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179) org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:673) com.consumer.StateMachineConsumer$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$496eff04.executeNextStep(<generated>) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:180) org.springframework.messaging.handler.invocation.InvocableHandlerMethod.invoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:112) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.HandlerAdapter.invoke(HandlerAdapter.java:49) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.invokeHandler(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:126) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.onMessage(MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.java:106) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.doInvokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:822) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:745) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$001(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$1.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:189) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.invokeListener(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1276) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.AbstractMessageListenerContainer.executeListener(AbstractMessageListenerContainer.java:726) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.doReceiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1219) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.receiveAndExecute(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1189) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer.access$1500(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:97) org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer$AsyncMessageProcessingConsumer.run(SimpleMessageListenerContainer.java:1421) java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)\nCaused by: java.lang.invoke.LambdaConversionException: Invalid receiver type interface org.apache.http.Header; not a subtype of implementation type interface org.apache.http.NameValuePair java.lang.invoke.AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.validateMetafactoryArgs(AbstractValidatingLambdaMetafactory.java:233) java.lang.invoke.LambdaMetafactory.metafactory(LambdaMetafactory.java:303) java.lang.invoke.CallSite.makeSite(CallSite.java:302)\n\t... 86 common frames omitted\n",
       "type":"run"
    }
```

Anybody faced a similar issue? Any help would be really appreciated. It smells like Apache HttpClient issue but doesn't know how to fix.

> UPDATE :

**Dependency Tree:**

```
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:booking-service-internal:jar:2.7.4:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.global.booking:booking-service:jar:2.11.4:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-zipkin:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-sleuth:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-context:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-rsa:jar:1.0.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |     \- org.bouncycastle:bcpkix-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  |        \- org.bouncycastle:bcprov-jdk15on:jar:1.55:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-core:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjrt:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-sleuth-zipkin:jar:1.2.2.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-commons:jar:1.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |     |  \- org.springframework.security:spring-security-crypto:jar:4.2.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |     +- io.zipkin.java:zipkin:jar:1.28.0:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- io.zipkin.reporter:zipkin-reporter:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- de.codecentric:spring-boot-admin-starter-client:jar:1.5.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |     \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-actuator:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-ui:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- io.springfox:springfox-spring-web:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger2:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.swagger:swagger-models:jar:1.5.13:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-spi:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |  \- io.springfox:springfox-core:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  |     \- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:jar:1.6.14:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-schema:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- io.springfox:springfox-swagger-common:jar:2.7.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  +- com.fasterxml:classmate:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-metadata:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.jolokia:jolokia-core:jar:1.3.7:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.codehaus.janino:janino:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.codehaus.janino:commons-compiler:jar:2.7.8:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.getsentry.raven:raven-logback:jar:7.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- com.getsentry.raven:raven:jar:7.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- biz.paluch.logging:logstash-gelf:jar:1.11.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:booking-rabbit:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-aop:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework:spring-beans:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-context:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.springframework:spring-expression:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-aop:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.aspectj:aspectjweaver:jar:1.8.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:booking-common:jar:2.13.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-logging:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jcl-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.slf4j:jul-to-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.slf4j:log4j-over-slf4j:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.data:spring-data-commons:jar:1.13.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.logstash.logback:logstash-logback-encoder:jar:4.7:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- ch.qos.logback:logback-core:jar:1.1.11:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-support:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-ws-core:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     |  \- org.springframework:spring-oxm:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.ws:spring-xml:jar:2.4.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-jms:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:transaction-repository:jar:4.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.mongodb:bson:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.mongodb:mongodb-driver-core:jar:3.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.data:spring-data-mongodb:jar:1.10.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.querydsl:querydsl-mongodb:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.querydsl:querydsl-core:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     +- com.mysema.commons:mysema-commons-lang:jar:0.2.4:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- com.infradna.tool:bridge-method-annotation:jar:1.13:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.querydsl:querydsl-codegen:jar:4.1.4:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- com.mysema.codegen:codegen:jar:0.6.8:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  |  \- org.eclipse.jdt.core.compiler:ecj:jar:4.3.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.reflections:reflections:jar:0.9.9:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     +- org.javassist:javassist:jar:3.21.0-GA:compile
[INFO] |  |  |     \- com.google.code.findbugs:annotations:jar:2.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- javax.jdo:jdo-api:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- javax.transaction:jta:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.projectlombok:lombok:jar:1.16.18:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:lifecycle-models:jar:1.7.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:booking-plugin-java-sdk:jar:4.5.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.global.booking:plugin-repository-sdk:jar:6.1.0:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.global.booking:plugin-repository-model:jar:4.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:jar:1.1.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.global.booking:booking-plugin-common:jar:4.3.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.global.booking:capabilities-models:jar:1.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:19.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.global.booking:addon-service-model:jar:1.2.3:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:device-control-sdk:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.global.booking:device-control-model:jar:1.0.0:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.global.booking:booking-common-sdk:jar:2.0.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:partner-accounts-java-sdk:jar:1.0.1-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-tomcat:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-core:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  +- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-el:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.apache.tomcat.embed:tomcat-embed-websocket:jar:8.5.16:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:jar:5.3.5.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  |  \- org.jboss.logging:jboss-logging:jar:3.3.1.Final:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework:spring-webmvc:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.assertj:assertj-core:jar:2.6.0:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:booking-adapter-java-sdk:jar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.global.booking:booking-adapter-model:jar:1.6.0-SNAPSHOT:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:opco-java-sdk:jar:1.8.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:jar:2.8.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:content-repository-sdk:jar:4.19.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.5:compile
[INFO] |  +- com.global.booking:content-repository-model:jar:4.19.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.global.booking:validator:jar:1.3.3:compile
[INFO] |     \- javax.validation:validation-api:jar:1.1.0.Final:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:customer-profile-java-sdk:jar:2.5.5:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.global.booking:customer-profile-model:jar:2.5.2:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:scheduler-java-sdk:jar:1.1.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.swagger:swagger-annotations:jar:1.5.10:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:addon-java-sdk:jar:1.4.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-hateoas:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- org.springframework.hateoas:spring-hateoas:jar:0.23.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.springframework.plugin:spring-plugin-core:jar:1.2.0.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310:jar:2.8.9:compile
[INFO] +- com.global.booking:subscription-info:jar:1.4.2:compile
[INFO] |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:3.0.1:compile
[INFO] +- org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:jar:3.5:compile
[INFO] +- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.9.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.2:compile
[INFO] +- org.modelmapper:modelmapper:jar:2.3.0:compile
[INFO] +- joda-time:joda-time:jar:2.9.9:compile
[INFO] +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- junit:junit:jar:4.12:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.mockito:mockito-core:jar:1.10.19:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  +- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:jar:1.4.0:test
[INFO] |  |  \- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:jar:0.0.20131108.vaadin1:test
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-core:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework:spring-test:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:test
[INFO] +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit-test:jar:1.7.3.RELEASE:test
[INFO] |  +- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-all:jar:1.3:test
[INFO] |  \- org.springframework.amqp:spring-rabbit:jar:1.7.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- com.rabbitmq:amqp-client:jar:4.0.2:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.retry:spring-retry:jar:1.2.1.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     +- org.springframework.amqp:spring-amqp:jar:1.7.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.springframework:spring-tx:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] +- com.github.fakemongo:fongo:jar:2.0.10:test
[INFO] |  +- org.mozilla:rhino:jar:1.7.7.1:test
[INFO] |  +- com.vividsolutions:jts:jar:1.13:test
[INFO] |  \- de.grundid.opendatalab:geojson-jackson:jar:1.2:test
[INFO] +- io.github.benas:random-beans:jar:3.6.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.objenesis:objenesis:jar:2.5.1:compile
[INFO] |  \- io.github.lukehutch:fast-classpath-scanner:jar:2.0.17:compile
[INFO] +- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:jar:2.2.0:compile
[INFO] |  +- net.minidev:json-smart:jar:2.2.1:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- net.minidev:accessors-smart:jar:1.1:compile
[INFO] |  |     \- org.ow2.asm:asm:jar:5.0.3:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:jar:1.7.25:compile
[INFO] +- software.amazon.awssdk:iot:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-json-protocol:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:protocol-core:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:sdk-core:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:profiles:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- org.reactivestreams:reactive-streams:jar:1.0.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:auth:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- software.amazon.eventstream:eventstream:jar:1.0.1:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:http-client-spi:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:regions:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:annotations:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:utils:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:aws-core:jar:2.7.17:compile
[INFO] |  +- software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client:jar:2.7.17:runtime
[INFO] |  \- software.amazon.awssdk:netty-nio-client:jar:2.7.17:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-codec-http2:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-codec:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-resolver:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-common:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-buffer:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-handler:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     +- io.netty:netty-transport-native-epoll:jar:linux-x86_64:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     |  \- io.netty:netty-transport-native-unix-common:jar:4.1.33.Final:runtime
[INFO] |     \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams-http:jar:2.0.0:runtime
[INFO] |        \- com.typesafe.netty:netty-reactive-streams:jar:2.0.0:runtime
[INFO] \- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-amqp:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:jar:1.5.6.RELEASE:compile
[INFO]    |  \- org.yaml:snakeyaml:jar:1.17:runtime
[INFO]    \- org.springframework:spring-messaging:jar:4.3.10.RELEASE:compile
```

> UPDATE :

**RABBITLISTENER CLASS:**

```
import com.booking.global.booking.service.BookingService;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Exchange;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.Queue;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.QueueBinding;
import org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.annotation.RabbitListener;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

import static com.bookingglobal.booking.service.BookingConstants.STATE_MACHINE;

@Component
public class BookingConsumer {

    private @Autowired
    BookingService bookingService;

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = BOOKING_EXECUTE_NEXT_STEP, durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = BOOKING_EXCHANGE, durable = "true"),
            key = BOOKING_EXECUTE_NEXT_STEP))
    void executeNextStep(String transactionId) {
        LOGGER.debug("Consuming a rabbit message from queue {} for transaction {}", BOOKING_EXECUTE_NEXT_STEP, transactionId);
        bookingService.executeNextStep(transactionId);
    }

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = BOOKING_EXECUTE_NEXT_STEP_WITH_DELAY, durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = BOOKING_DELAYED_EXCHANGE, durable = "true", delayed = "true"),
            key = BOOKING_EXECUTE_NEXT_STEP_WITH_DELAY))
    void executeNextStepWithDelay(String transactionId) {
        LOGGER.debug("Consuming a rabbit message from queue {} for transaction {}", BOOKING_EXECUTE_NEXT_STEP_WITH_DELAY, transactionId);
        bookingService.executeNextStep(transactionId);
    }

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = BOOKING_RETRY_FAILED_STEP, durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = BOOKING_DELAYED_EXCHANGE, durable = "true", delayed = "true"),
            key = BOOKING_RETRY_FAILED_STEP))
    void retryFailedStep(String transactionId) {
        LOGGER.debug("Consuming a rabbit message from queue {} for transaction {}", BOOKING_RETRY_FAILED_STEP, transactionId);
        bookingService.retryStep(transactionId);
    }

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = BOOKING_STEP_TIMEOUT_TIMER, durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = BOOKING_DELAYED_EXCHANGE, durable = "true", delayed = "true"),
            key = BOOKING_STEP_TIMEOUT_TIMER))
    void handleStepTimeout(StepTimeoutTimerMessage message) {
        String transactionId = message.getTransactionId();
        LOGGER.debug("Consuming a rabbit message from queue {} for transaction {}", BOOKING_STEP_TIMEOUT_TIMER, transactionId);
        bookingService.timeoutStep(transactionId, message.getStepCorrelationId());
    }

    @RabbitListener(bindings = @QueueBinding(
            value = @Queue(value = BOOKING_STEP_TIMEOUT_TIMER_V2, durable = "true", autoDelete = "false"),
            exchange = @Exchange(value = BOOKING_DELAYED_EXCHANGE, durable = "true", delayed = "true"),
            key = BOOKING_STEP_TIMEOUT_TIMER_V2))
    void handleStepTimeoutV2(StepTimeoutMessageV2 message) {
        LOGGER.debug("Consuming a rabbit message from queue {} for transaction {}", BOOKING_STEP_TIMEOUT_TIMER_V2, message.getStepUid());
        bookingService.timeoutStep(message.getStepUid());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like Apache HTTP Client incompatibility.

Consider to exclude `com.rabbitmq:http-client` artifact from Spring AMQP dependency.

Let's assume you have a Maven project generated via Spring Start IO site! So, you must have something like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

So, you just add an exclusion:

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.rabbitmq</groupId>
                <artifactId>http-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

That's my best guess what is going on and let's hope you don't use RabbitMQ Management API: https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/docs/current/reference/html/#management-rest-api !

Comment: Still, it is not working. I have disabled this dependency in spring-rabbit-test as well. Why it is trying to bootstrap using  AmazonHttpClient?

Comment: I don't know whether I have RabbitMQ Management API in my project? How shall we check whether do we have RabbitMQ Management API dependency?

Comment: OK. So, time to scan your dependency tree and see who brings for us a wrong HTTP Client: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html. You should understand if you use  RabbitMQ Management API  reading the doc I've pointed.

Comment: In the maven dependency..I couldn't see any http-client apart from the one from aws. How can I share my dependency-tree? Shall I edit the question with dependency tree?

Comment: Yes, you can edit your question. BTW, the Spring RabbitMQ does not use AWS: it is your code which call something on AWS, and there already you have a mix of jars for HTTP Client library. So, please, share a dependency tree and we'll what what may be wrong there!

Comment: Yep, that's true. I am using aws SDK to create things in aws iot. I updated the question with Dependency tree. Your help will be really appreciable.

Comment: Problem is from software.amazon.awssdk:apache-client. But I would like to know why RabbitMQ reads this client? Is there any option in RabbitMQ to avoid reading client classes?

Comment: RabbitMQ doesn't do that. It is your code calls an AWS API and that one really relies on the Apache HTTP Client. There is no other way in AWS Java SDK.

Comment: Sorry, have no idea what is going on. Is there really a strong requirements to use AWS SDK v2 ? Any chances that you can share with us a simple project to reproduce? but anyway it fully doesn't look like Spring or RabbitMQ Client problem. There is some version mismatch in transitive dependencies of AWS SDK. You can try to use `--verbose` flag for your Java process to determine from which jars the `org.apache.http.NameValuePair` and `org.apache.http.Header` are  loaded.

Comment: Actually, when I run aws-sdk alone it works fine we are getting the above issue the moment I add rabbitMQ dependency. You can check the error message is from the following class "org.springframework.amqp.rabbit.listener.SimpleMessageListenerContainer". That's why I suspect RabbitMQ. Wierd.

Comment: Well, we need to see your code for the `@RabbitListener`. I believe that you can AWS Client from there and such a method is really called from the mentioned `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`

Comment: I have updated my question with RabbitListener class. Thanks a lot for your kind reply. Kindly let me know if you need any more inputs.

Comment: Yeah... Sorry, doesn't say anything to me. Could you, please, come up with more accurate stack trace to share? I somehow believe there should be a reference to you code as well.

Comment: I am running aws-iot logic inside RabbitMQ consumer. That  could be the issue? I mean registerThing, creareThing etc

Comment: So, you've just confirmed my assumptions, but that still should not be an issue. That's why I'm asking about using AWS SDK v2. Seeing your error, it looks like a problem is on the response side. Might be just the problem with Jackson JSON processors... Investigate which version is required for that IOT API and what is used in your classpath